# Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1572863 in /home/bitrix/ext_www/path.to.site/xls/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php

Tags: php, phpexcel

Пробую прочитать excel-файл с помощью библиотеки `PHPExcel`.

Код страницы:

```
require_once ('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
$xls = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('xls.xls');
```

Открываем страницу в браузере, видим бесконечные записи такого вида:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1572863 in /home/bitrix/ext_www/path.to.site/xls/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php on line 309
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1572860 in /home/bitrix/ext_www/path.to.site/xls/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLERead.php on line 316
```

`private static function getInt4d($data, $pos)
    {
        // FIX: represent numbers correctly on 64-bit system
        // http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1487372&group_id=99160&atid=623334
        // Hacked by Andreas Rehm 2006 to ensure correct result of the <<24 block on 32 and 64bit systems
        $_or_24 = ord($data[$pos + 3]);//309str
        if ($_or_24 >= 128) {
            // negative number
            $_ord_24 = -abs((256 - $_or_24) << 24);
        } else {
            $_ord_24 = ($_or_24 & 127) << 24;
        }
        return ord($data[$pos]) | (ord($data[$pos + 1]) << 8) | (ord($data[$pos + 2]) << 16) | $_ord_24;//316str
    }`

В чём причина ошибки?

Comment: откуда мы знаем что там у вас на 309 строке..

Comment: Изменил описание. Добавил описание метода и отметил 309, 316 строки

Answer (score 0):

Вам не стоит использовать библиотеку PHPExcel, т.к. она уже не поддерживается, для работы с xls, есть [новая версия этой библиотеки](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).

Понять в чем причина по вашему вопросу не представляется возможным, т.к. ошибка происходит внутри библиотеки, и никто кроме вас не может воспроизвести эту ошибку с вашими данными.